# Method glFrustumf() on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Today, I had the privilege to study OpenGL ES on Android Developer webpage and I run into some issues, understanding a couple of methods.

On Android Developer document: [GL10.glFrustumf(float, float, float, float, float, float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#glFrustumf(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float)). It has no description about this function. I searched it on Google but did not get a positive result as well. So I was hoping if anyone within the group can kindly share any document about how to use glFrustumf() method  with me?

Second issue: [Projection and camera view in OpenGL ES 1.0](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#proj-es1) It has the following: `gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);`

I wonder that why it is 3 and 7 on the last parameter?

Answer (score 1):

[`glFrustum`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml) is a legacy OpenGL function that sets a projection matrix.

The 3 and 7 specify the distance from the "camera" to the near and far clipping planes, respectively.  Objects closer than 3 units or farther than 7 units from the "camera" won't be seen under the frustum matrix.

Comment: Do you have any document about it? Or some Google key word be okay. Please share me. Thank you for your helping me.

Comment: The document is linked in my answer: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml

Comment: Since the question is about ES, the man page would be this one: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glFrustum.xml. Not surprisingly, they look very similar. There is one difference: The ES version takes `GLfloat` arguments, while the desktop OpenGL version takes `GLdouble`.